# Error with Actions observable in @ngrx/effects using TypeScript 2.4.1

Tags: typescript, ngrx

After updating to TypeScript 2.4.1, compiling projects that use the `Actions` observable from `@ngrx/effects` (version 2.0.3) sees the following error thrown:

```
Error TS2684: The 'this' context of type 'Actions' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<any>'.
Error TS7006: Parameter 'action' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Error TS2345: Argument of type 'Actions' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<Action>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '(operator: Operator<any, Action>) => Observable<Action>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<Action, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Types of parameters 'operator' and 'operator' are incompatible.
        Type 'Operator<Action, R>' is not assignable to type 'Operator<any, Action>'.
          Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'Action'.
```

How can this be resovled?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TypeScript 2.4.1 more strictly enforces the the generic signature of the `lift` method in `Observable` and the `Actions` observable's implementation of `lift` fails the check.

The check can be disabled using the `--noStrictGenericChecks` command line flag or the `noStrictGenericChecks` compiler option (as a parameter in `tsconfig.json`'s `"compilerOptions"` object).

An alternative to disabling the checks is to use TypeScript's interface augmentation to specify a correct signature:

```ts
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Operator } from "rxjs/Operator";

declare module "@ngrx/effects/src/actions" {
    interface Actions {
        lift<R>(operator: Operator<Action, R>): Observable<R>;
    }
}
```

Note that the full path to the module/file must be used; it's not sufficient to specify `@ngrx/effects` as the module name.

---

This has been resolved with the release of `@ngrx/effects` [2.0.4](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#204-2017-07-09).

Comment: I was getting a similar error related to the `Subject` class. The fix was to upgrade the rxjs package (to 5.5.7 in my case).