# Observable.forkJoin() TS2322 error after updating to TypeScript 2.4.1 and Rxjs 5.4.2

Tags: typescript, rxjs5, typescript2.4

In our angular 4.2.4 application, we use RxJS's `Observable.forkJoin` in a number of places to return heterogeneous types.

For example:

```
private fleet: Aircraft[];
private contractList: string[];

Observable.forkJoin([
  this.fleetService.getFleet(),
  this.fleetService.getContractList()
]).subscribe(
  next => {
    this.fleet = results[0];
    this.contractList = results[1];
  },
  error => console.error
);
```

with the following service signatures:

```
getFleet(): Observable<Aircraft[]> { ... }
getContractList(): Observable<string[]> { ... }
```

**After updating to TypeScript 2.4.1**, `tsc` now complains with the following errors for `this.contractList`:

> ERROR in ./app/fleet/fleetComponent.ts (xx,xx):
>   error TS2322: Type 'Aircraft[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

But I'm not trying to assign an `Aircraft[]` to a `string[]`.

The same is true for *all* the other `Observable.forkJoin` we implement: all elements in `result[]` are treated as though they were the same type as `result[0]`.

It seems very similar to the problem in [Error with Actions observable in @ngrx/effects using TypeScript 2.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938803/error-with-actions-observable-in-ngrx-effects-using-typescript-2-4-1) but adding `"noStrictGenericChecks": true,` to tsconfig.js' `"compilerOptions"` did not solve the problem.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably seeing the increased enforcement from the Typescript compiler on generics, the side-effect being that forkJoin doesn't have a `tuple` overloads.

Removing the array notation from the parameter list to `forkJoin` should work, however:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.fleetService.getFleet(),
  this.fleetService.getContractList()
).subscribe(
  next => {
    this.fleet = results[0];
    this.contractList = results[1];
  },
  error => console.error
);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't even know you could pass a list to `forkJoin()`. That did solve the problem, and I appreciate the explanation with `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I think it's better to use [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) as `combineLatest` fetch and return data as soon as available but `forkJoin` will wait until last chain command executes.

Comment: It is 2 very different uses