# Can't handle json files returned by Observable.forkJoin()

Tags: json, angular, observable, fork-join

I'm working with Angular2 and a nodejs rest api. I have to do one or more http request for a same task so I'm using Observable.forkJoin() to wait for all of them to finish.
I map the result with the json parsing method and then subscribe to this result but **I can't get any json properties from the result the way I used to do.**

My service method returns the Observable.forkJoin() itself:

```
public rename(file:MyFile, newName:string){
    let requests = new Array();
    for(let i=0; i<file.sources.length; i++){
        let url:string = this.serverUrl;
        if(src.name === "src1"){
            url += "rename/src1";
        } else if (src.name === "src2" ){
            url += "rename/src2";
        }
        requests[i] = this.http.get(url)
                  .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                  .catch(this.handleError);
    }
    return Observable.forkJoin(requests);
}
```

Then I subscribe to it in another method elsewhere:

```
this.api.rename(this.selectedFile, newFileName).subscribe(
    rep => {
      // The editor tells me "Property 'name' doesn't exist on type '{}'."
      console.log(rep[0].name); 
    },
    err => { console.error(err); }
  );
```

The server correctly respond with the data I asked. The rep[0] is correctly set, it looks like this:

```
Object {name: "res.png", id: "HyrBvB6H-", size: 0, type: "", isShared: false…}
```

I suppose it's a typing problem. Usually, with a simple http.get request, it returns an 'any' object. Here it returns an '[]{}' object. `res[0]` is an '{}' object and I can't get the json properties on it.

Am I using the Observer.forkJoin() correctly? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: What if you make `new Array<any>();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is the editor complaining and it is **not** an error when the code executes, it likely is a typing problem. You can set the return type of `rename()` to:

```
public rename(file:MyFile, newName:string): Observable<any[]> { }
```

This should allow you access properties of the inner results such as `name`.

Or you can type the `rep` array in `subscribe()` as `any[]`:

```
this.api.rename(this.selectedFile, newFileName).subscribe(
    (rep: any[]) => {
      console.log(rep[0].name); 
    },
    err => { console.error(err); }
);
```

If all else fails or doesn't work for your solution you can use Type Assertion to treat `rep` as `any[]`:

```
this.api.rename(this.selectedFile, newFileName).subscribe(
    rep => {
      const responses = rep as any as any[];
      console.log(responses[0].name); 
    },
    err => { console.error(err); }
);
```

If the results structure is consistent across the different endpoints, it would best practice to create an interface/class to replace `any[]` with.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I feel stupid, I just added the return type Observable<any[]> on the method and it instantly worked well.
I though it would not be necessary because of the 'any'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`http.get` is a asynchronous process, so you can't use for loop.
Syntactically you have to nest the gets inside forkJoin, so you have something like this. You can use the for loop to build an array of urls first.:

```
return Observable.forkJoin([
    this.http.get(url[1]).map(res => res.json()),
    this.http.get(url[2]).map(res => res.json()),
    this.http.get(url[3]).map(res => res.json())
  ])
  .map((data: any[]) => {
     this.part1 = data[0];
     this.part2 = data[1];
     this.part3 = data[2];
  });
```

I wonder if you may be able to do something like this. I'll have a try tomorrow. It's late..

```
return Observable.forkJoin(let req = [];
  for(let i=0; i<file.sources.length; i++){
      req[i] = this.http.get(url[i]).map(res => res.json())
  }
)
```

Comment: Note that with that current latest tsc (2.4.1) and angular (4.3.0) you *need* to drop the array notation for `.forkJoin()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020250/observable-forkjoin-ts2322-error-after-updating-to-typescript-2-4-1-and-rxjs-5

Comment: Oh... that sounds promising then.. So maybe the for loop cal be nested without the req array I was assigning..

Comment: Thanks for answering :) The problem was purely on the objects type. I'll remove the array notation according to what you pointed out @msanford

Comment: @JGFMK You can just pass a list of functions because `.forkJoin()` uses a `...rest` parameter anyway: you simply remove the brackets and use it as you normally would.

Comment: @msanford So you are saying we can now do either way?

Comment: @JGFMK Not exactly, see the (my) question I linked above. With TypeScript > 2.4.0 the strict generics checker cause the array-notated version to fail. Prior to 2.4, yes, both will work.

Comment: @msanford - Sorry... Crossed wires I interpreted as you following up on your first comment, not responding to my first response. Face palms!